# how to add facebook authentication to my Rest app in JAVA

Tags: java, restful-authentication, facebook-authentication

I created a RESTful application with  jersey and now I'm trying to add a facebook authentication interface to my app and i'm kinda stuck how to connect authentication to my rest method .

```
package service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import metier.Cours;


@Path("rs")
public class Formation {
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/FraisAnnuelles/{code}")
    public Double FraisInscription(@PathParam(value="code")int code) {
        return (Double)(30000+(Math.random()*(30000-25000)));
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("/Cours/{code}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Cours getCours(@PathParam(value="code")int code) {
        return new Cours(code,"web semantique",30);
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("/ListeCours")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Cours> getAllCours(){
        
        List<Cours> listeCours=new ArrayList<>();
        listeCours.add(new Cours(1,"web semantique",30));
        listeCours.add(new Cours(2,"web service",20));
        listeCours.add(new Cours(3,"IAD",26));
        return listeCours;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you will be able to do that. The protocol that is used for logging in with facebook/google/some_identity_provider is
[OpenID connect](https://openid.net/connect/). That itself is a big can of worms to dive into when starting from scratch, but the key element in why I have some doubts to the feasibility of what you are asking for is that for a login using openid connect to be successful, the identity provider has a database table with a list of allowed urls to log in from, and unless the url you try to log in from matches exactly 100% one of the values in that table, the login attempt will fail.

So in other words, in order to allow users to log in with facebook/google on https://myblog.example.com/blog you need to contact facebook/google and ask them "hey facebook/google, can you add https://myblog.example.com/blog to the list urls allowed to log in from pretty please?". I assume both companies require some (significant) minimum size of your web site before allowing logging in with them, and you will be absolutely at the whim of their terms and condition with zero negotiation possibilities. You might need to pay for the privileged to use them as identity providers.

Comment: I'm new to this ,It's just a simple REST app ,with no database .I'm trying to do some kind of authentication with facebook to be able then to get ListCours with GET request as shown above with REST .